# Jquery traversal Issue

Tags: jquery, traversal

```
<tr>
   <td class="vb">
        <b>NAME:<span class="formvalidation"> *</span></b>
   </td>
   <td class="vb">
    <span dir="none">
        <input name="xyz" type="text" maxlength="255" id="fc95c5086638_ff3_new_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="NAME" class="long spellcheck-true"><br>
        <span class="formvalidation">
            <span role="alert">You must specify a value for this required field.</span><br>
        </span>
    </span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="vb">
       <b>NAME:<span class="formvalidation"> *</span></b></td><td class="vb">
       <span dir="none">
        <input name="abc" type="text" maxlength="255" id="fc95c5086638_ff3_new_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="NAME" class="long spellcheck-true"><br>
       </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

...
....

**Problem**

there are some `<td>` contains `<span dir='none'>` which is having two children `<input>` and `<span>`
and there are some `<td>` contains `<span dir='none'>` which is only having one children `<input>`
and i want to add class to `<input>` element which is having two children
Can anybody help me how i can do it using jquery.

Comment: Do you want to add it to both inputs if there are two?

Comment: Thanks Adam for responding I want to add class for the first case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) iterate through `span` with attribute `dir="none"` like

```
$("td span[dir='none']").each(function () {
});
```

2) Now get its children of `input` elements

```
var spa = $(this).find('input');
```

3) Now check its length, if it has 2 then iterate those `input` elements and add a new class to them.

```
if (spa.length == 2) {
    spa.each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('newClass');
    });
}
```

Finally,

```
$("td span[dir='none']").each(function () {
    var spa = $(this).find('input');
    if (spa.length == 2) {
        spa.each(function () {
            $(this).addClass('newClass');
        });
    }
});
```

As per your comments,

```
$("span[dir='none']").each(function () {     
    if($(this).children("span").hasClass("formvalidation")) { 
        $(this).children("input").addClass("newClass"); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: there is only one input in <span dir='none'> the difference is that there are some <span dir='none'> contain <span> along with <input>

Comment: @AshutoshVerma ok, then change `if (spa.length == 1) {`

Comment: @AshutoshVerma Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/vA6CG/ inspect to see whether new class is added.

Comment: it adding class to both type input

Comment: @AshutoshVerma I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: praveen still some issue

Comment: @AshutoshVerma what is the issue?

Comment: it is adding class to both type input

Comment: @AshutoshVerma yes it will. See the HTML in fiddle.  Your condition satisfied right?

Comment: i want to add class to the <input> which is along<span class="formvalidation">

Comment: @AshutoshVerma have you checked your html, there is `input` tag in `:<span class="formvalidation">`

Comment: Oh i mean to say with the reference of children of <span dir="none">

Comment: Praveen i have post the answer for my question, actually this what i was looking for but your answer shown me the path

Comment: $("span[dir='none']").each(function () {      
      if($(this).children("span").hasClass("formvalidation"))
      {
       $(this).children("input").addClass("newClass");
      }
  });

Comment: @AshutoshVerma Glad to hear that you have figured a way.